# mat-tab-group exceeds parent div width

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I've a searched about this problem, and seems it's because `mat-tab-group` was created also with flex layouts, and for some reason, it's interfering or ignoring the widths of the parent div.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="50vh" style="background-color: cyan;" *ngIf="selectedService$ | async as selectedService"> 
    <!-- SPECIFIC PANEL -->
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="15vw" style="background-color: blueviolet;">  
      <!-- STUB -->
    </div>
    <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="85vw">
      <mat-tab-group>          
        <mat-tab label="Records">
          <ng-template matTabContent>
            <app-voice-records>
              <!-- COOL GRAPH GOES HERE -->
            </app-voice-records>
          </ng-template>
        </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

How it looks. It shouldn't surpass the cyan background.
[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you try removing the vw from the fxFlex on the columns? You also could try fxFill in the parent container

Comment: How would I divide the space then ?

Comment: Just remove the unit not the number!

Comment: Gj, it worked! But why ? Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes vh and vw don't behave as expected. Seeing your layout it was evident that for some reason it wasn't taking the full width of the screen for it's calculations and this could be one of the side effects of using those units. This is because vh for example is equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block and this containing block is not always the same. Also when fxFlex is being used I usually see people not using the units and often just using the number that I think that defaults to percentages which are, to me, more reliable but I think it all boils down to which block is taken as the initial containing one by the layout.

Comment: Alright thanks friend. There's still 15 min before I can assign the bounty, I'll do it later !